# Multithreaded WCF Server with Entity Framework: transactions and synchronization, race condition

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio, entity-framework, race-condition

I have multithreaded C# WCF server with resources stored in database.
I'm accessing db with EF.

Server is handling requests from many workers.
Workers are connected in groups.
Each group has his own resources in database.
Some group has some resources shared with another group.

All requests are about resources: synchronization, creating, updating, deleting.

I have a problem with race condition:
If workers A and B are with the same group, worker A request some update, then B request synchronization, and B's request would start and end before A's request will end, then worker B would never get A's update.

Is there any way with entity framework to do atomic operations like `get_and_increase_if`?
I would like to implement semaphore like tool on database value.

Is there any other way to resolve this problem?

Synchronization is done by revision counter.
Group has revision.
Creating/Updating is done by:

1. `Increase group revision()`
2. `Set new/updated object revision to new group revision()`

Edit: There are many resources types, each in its own table in db. So I can't just set next value as revision for resource.

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I find this question very vague. What are these groups you are talking about? What is this synchronization request you are talking about? Why should your different requests interact? Why can't you solve this with database transactions?

Comment: @Steven Worker ask for synchronization, it has its own revision. Server simply checks if there is something new for worker's revision (`if worker.revision < worker.group.revision`). If its true, server checks what is new and send it to worker. It won't work if A is updating, so A.group.revision is increased. B is synchronizing, server return all new (there is no last A changes), B has revision = group revision, A is ending updating, A changes are marked with same revision B just get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a counter of next revision number that you need, you could use sequences, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

If it is more complicated you could use serializable transactions.

Comment: It's not that simple. I have many different resources in many different tables. Added to question.

Comment: Then the way to go is to use a transaction scope with the isolation level set to serializable

Comment: I thought about it, but I can't find a way to 1) get value from db, 2) increase it and 3) set some properties of other objects to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SqlServer 2005 or above:

```
UPDATE GroupRevisions SET Revision = Revision+1
OUTPUT INSERTED.Revision
WHERE GroupRevisionID = @Id
```

Comment: Why?  Entity Framework has facilities for calling sql directly.  More to the point, you're doing something complex and definitely not built into Entity Framework; this is *exactly why* those facilities are there.

Comment: Maybe, but I would be very hard for me now to do it that way.